# How to print a variable in a directory using python script

Tags: python

```
    #!/usr/bin/python
    import os
    import pathlib
    import os.path
    from datetime import datetime
    i = datetime.now()
    datess = i.strftime('%d')
    months = ["Unknown",
              "Jan",
              "Feb",
              "Mar",
              "Apr",
              "May",
              "Jun",
              "Jul",
              "Aug",
              "Sep",
              "Oct",
              "Nov",
              "Dec"]

    now = (datetime.now())
    year = (now.year)
    print (year)
    month = (months[now.month])
    print(month)
    # I want to print C:\apache-tomcat\store\retail_sector\sugar\Year.month/date
    #The exact path is C:\apache-tomcat\store\retail_sector\sugar\2017.aug/24 but i want to print the year and date as varible 
    p = pathlib.Path('C:\apache-tomcat\store\retail_sector\sugar\2017.aug/24')
    if p.is_dir(): 
    print "Directory is created"
```

File path is C:\apache-tomcat\store\retail_sector\sugar\2017.aug/24 but i want print year date as varible like C:\apache-tomcat\store\retail_sector\sugar\Year.month/date. Plese help me how to do this.

Comment: Something like this ?, `path = r'C:\apache-tomcat\store\retail_sector\sugar\%s' % (now.strftime('%Y.%b\%d'))` [strftime() and strptime() Behavior](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)

Comment: Thanks. Working now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you want to do, one possibility is to use the `time.strftime` [function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime) which allows you to convert date to your specified format:

```
import time

now = time.localtime()

date_string = time.strftime('%Y.%b/%d', now)
print(date_string)
```

This will print

```
'2017.Aug/24'
```

The `'%Y.%b/%d'` part specifies the format, `%Y` represents year, `%b` represents abbreviated month name, and `%d` represents date of the month. You can find a complete list of available formats in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime).

You can then use your `date_string` to build your path:

```
path_string = '/my/test/path/%s' % date_string
print(path_string)
```

This will print:

```
'/my/test/path/2017.Aug/24'
```

If you want the month to be lowercase, you can use

```
path_string = '/my/test/path/%s' % date_string.lower()
```